# Example for implementing the unscented kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filters, unscented-kalman-filter

Currently, I'm learning about the UKF and in order to understand it in a good way, I programmed it, however in order to see it working I need a problem to solve which I can't now find.

**Can you please recommend a very basic problem in which all the equations and the data are explained and ready to implement in my code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but the [IEEE Proceedings paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/Julier_Uhlmann_mar04.pdf) by Julier and Uhlmann in section **VI. B** has a nice example:

> Consider the problem that is illustrated in Fig. 8. A vehicle enters
> the atmosphere at high altitude and at a very high speed. The position
> of the body is tracked by a radar which measures range and bearing.
> This type of problem has been identified by a number of authors [1](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/Julier_Uhlmann_mar04.pdf),
> [9]–[11] as being particularly stressful for filters and trackers
> because of the strong nonlinearities exhibited by the forces which act
> on the vehicle.

[image: Figure 8 of the paper.]